# Upload to S3 bucket using SAM template

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have created a S3 bucket made it public using SAM template, is there any way I cloud upload objects to bucket from the template

Comment: Cloudformation template? Its not clear what you are asking for.

Comment: the question is plenty clear, I was wondering the same. SAM = superset of cloudformation. Cloudformation can deploy an Api Gateway stage using `AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment` so an s3 upload seemed reasonable but doesn't appear to be a thing

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with SAM, but I know that **CloudFormation cannot populate the contents of a bucket**.

One workaround is to create a [CloudFormation Custom Resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html), which triggers an AWS Lambda function during the stack deployment. The Lambda function can then copy files, such as copying them between S3 buckets.

I have written such a function. If you do it well, you could a list of the files to copy as **parameters** within the CloudFormation template, so that the same function can be used in multiple templates. Writing your first Custom Resource function can be challenging, since it needs to 'return' differently to normal functions.

Comment: SAM does not differ from CloudFormation in this regard. It is only a preprocessor for CloudFormation, so custom resources would be the only way if you want this functionality triggered by CloudFormation itself.